# Get the solution for analyzer

Tags: c#, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

I'm creating na analyzer for Visual Studio, and I need the Solution property required by SymbolFinder.FindSourceDefinitionAsync(ISymbol, Solution) to ensure that I'm really operating over the type I want.

```
public static async Task<ITypeSymbol> GetBaseScenario(ITypeSymbol type)
    {
        if (type == null)
            return null;

        var origType = await SymbolFinder.FindSourceDefinitionAsync(type, _solution);
        if (BaseScnSymbols.Contains(origType) || BaseVersionScnSymbols.Contains(origType))
            return origType as ITypeSymbol;

        return null;
    }
```

I can get the Semantic Model, the compilation, but I can't get the solution. 
How can I get the solution? Is there a better approach for this problem?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? There's probably a way to do that without the solution.

Comment: I've posted an [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44162908/1938988) on how to do so

Answer (score 2):

You cannot and generally should not try to access the Solution during an analyzer. This is for performance and correctness. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23203916/972216) still applies. If you describe your actual scenario there's generally a way to not get the Solution.

Comment: Well, in a MethodDeclarationSyntax I'm finding all symbols which have a specific BaseType. I want to extract all hardcoded values associated with those symbols in creationExpression, initializers, assignments and invocations. I was using await SymbolFinder.FindDerivedClassesAsync(namedTS, _solution) to get all the symbols that derive from wanted BaseType, but now I don't have the solution which makes me loop each symbol BaseType.OriginalDefinition to find if the symbol derives or not from it. Was I clear? Do you want me to edit the question?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know the only way to get a solution symbol is to load it via its physical path with [MSBuildWorkspace.OpenSolutionAsync](http://www.coderesx.com/roslyn/html/8BC51520.htm).

Comment: Wouldn't that create a mismatch between symbols/syntaxnodes because the object instances are diferent?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand what you mean by that.

Comment: What I'm trying to say is that, if I manually open the solution, it won't be related with the semantic model that I get from the contex in DiagnosticAnalyzer, meaning that SymbolFinder.FindSourceDefinitionAsync() won't match the given symbol with the SourceDefinition. Am I'm wrong?

Comment: It seems like there is no straightforward way to do what you want to do. I've found this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23203206/roslyn-current-workspace-in-diagnostic-with-code-fix-project, which is about a similar issue. It is more than 2 years old though, so there might have been some advancements in the topic.

Comment: Guess I'll have to try another approach. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Sorry we couldn't find a solution :/ Good luck!

Comment: The reason why there's no example for this is that `solution` is not available in a nuget package based analyzer. If you only target VSIX, then you can get a hold of `EnvDTE`, and from that you can get access to the `VisualStudioWorkspace`, which has a reference to the solution.