# Roslyn Find All assignments made to a Field

Tags: c#, roslyn, analyzer

I'm trying write an analyzer, I need to find all assignments made to a field using Roslyn.

```
private async static Task<bool> VariableDoesNotMutate(SyntaxNodeAnalysisContext context, VariableDeclaratorSyntax firstVariable)
{
    var variableSymbol = context.SemanticModel.GetDeclaredSymbol(firstVariable);
    var references = await SymbolFinder.FindReferencesAsync(variableSymbol, context.GetSolution());

    foreach (var reference in references)
    {
        //How do I check for assignment?
    }

    //need to filter by assignments
    return references.Count() > 1;
}
```

I heard using the symbolFinder was correct, but I'm not sure how to do this.
The symbol finder requires a solution, which I only have access to through a hack, so I'm assuming there is another way to do this.

Issues:

1. When I try to Find all references to a variable only the Declaration is returned an I do not find any other references how can I fix this?
2. Once I have a reference How can I determine if it's an assignment?

Comment: You're probably searching in the wrong `Solution` instance.

Comment: @SLaks How Can I use a Find All Assignments to a symbol, When  Analyzer's don't have a public way to find get the solution?

Comment: For performance reasons, you cannot / should not do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Couldn't find any references originally because my document was not in the correct solution. Analyzer's don't provide you a way to get to the Solution and as @SLaks say's for preformance reasons you should not do this:

To Get the Solution You need to reflect into the AnalyzerOptions I've written an answer how to do so [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44162908/1938988)

However, If you need to you can do this Get The Equivalent Symbol in the Solution and work off of that.  This is potentially dangerous

```
static async Task<ISymbol> GetEquivalentSymbol(SyntaxNodeAnalysisContext context, FieldDeclarationSyntax field, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var solution = context.GetSolution();
    var classDeclaration = field.Ancestors().OfType<ClassDeclarationSyntax>().FirstOrDefault();
    var namespaceDeclaration = field.Ancestors().OfType<NamespaceDeclarationSyntax>().FirstOrDefault();

    var className = classDeclaration?.Identifier.ValueText;

    var initialVariable = field.Declaration.Variables.FirstOrDefault();

    foreach (var project in solution.Projects)
    {
        foreach (var document in project.Documents)
        {
            var semanticModel = await document.GetSemanticModelAsync(cancellationToken);
            var root = await document.GetSyntaxRootAsync(cancellationToken);
            if (null != namespaceDeclaration)
            {
                var namespaceNode = root.DescendantNodes().OfType<NamespaceDeclarationSyntax>()
                    .FirstOrDefault(node => node.Name.ToString() == namespaceDeclaration.Name.ToString());
                if (null == namespaceNode)
                {
                    continue;
                }
            }

            var classNode = root.DescendantNodes()
                .OfType<ClassDeclarationSyntax>()
                .FirstOrDefault(node => node.Identifier.ValueText == className);

            var desiredField = classNode?.DescendantNodes().OfType<FieldDeclarationSyntax>()
                .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Declaration.Variables.First().Identifier.ValueText == initialVariable.Identifier.ValueText);

            if (desiredField == null)
            {
                continue;
            }

            var symbol = semanticModel.GetDeclaredSymbol(desiredField.Declaration.Variables.FirstOrDefault());
            return symbol;
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

Then you can get the references like so:

```
var equivalentSymbol = await GetEquivalentSymbol(context, field, cancellationToken);

var references = await SymbolFinder.FindReferencesAsync(equivalentSymbol, context.GetSolution(), cancellationToken);
```