# Roslyn Analyzer to analyse and modify csproj file

Tags: csproj, roslyn-code-analysis

Currently I have a script that modifies nuget reference paths in old style csproj files. (for anyone that is interested this is due to building using different solutions which breaks the NuGet reference paths. I have reported it to Microsoft and it is currently in triage).

The script works correctly and does what I need it to, however I thought that this would be a good candidate for a Roslyn Analyzer with a Code fix.

I have played around with analysers and have been able to write several that can modify code within a project, but I am having great difficulty writing one that can work on the csproj file itself.

I have looked at workspaces (VisualStudioWorkspace and MSBuildWorkspace) however it seems to me that these will give you access to the various projects in a solution but will not give you access to the project file itself?

If anyone can give me a pointer to where/what I should be looking for, or if it is actually possible, i'd very much appreciate it.

Thank you

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: I did not. I'm still interested to know if and how this is possible so if you figure it out please let me know. Good luck

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23203206/roslyn-current-workspace-in-diagnostic-with-code-fix-project suggests that it is not possible. I solved my own "problem" by using a custom msbuild-task that fails when certain properties contradict my own "rules"